# How cheats made for multiplayer games (ex: Tibia) accesses information from the client (in this case, C++)?

Tags: c++, memory, automation, code-injection

Tibia is an online multiplayer game which works via a C++ client ([image](http://www.nerdweek.com.br/wp-content/uploads/2011/12/tibia.jpg)). There are some cheating tools that allow, for example, changing the look of your char, using recovery items when your HP hits a certain point and even depicting the map without aesthetics ([image](http://blackdtools.com/screenshotsbsc/menu03.jpg)).

How can those software access the internal memory used by Tibia and how do they figure out where specific information is stored?

Comment: @downvoter, care to explain?

Comment: Under what OS? Nearly every OS will let one process access another process' memory (e.g., to support debuggers). The details vary widely though. Figuring out what's where is typically a matter of using one of those debuggers to see what changes happen under what circumstances.

Comment: @JerryCoffin Hmm I see. I was not aware of that. Any question explaining some general concepts and googleable names would be very useful as an answer. The example I provided is for a C++ client under Windows, but I would appreciate information on acessing the memory of a Flash client.

Comment: This does not appear to be a practical programming problem.

Comment: @RaymondChen I don't agree. Why do you think so?

Comment: @Dokkat Because it's not about programming, but about using some already existing tools. Also it's a way too broad question I fear. You can look for "reverse engineering" though. Also there are existing programs for exactly your purpose, just can't remember the name

Comment: @Voo that does not make sense, someone has to make those tools and doing so is a programming problem.

Comment: @Dokkat: Nobody really has to make them, but it's still far too broad a question to reasonably answer here. How to write a debugger for Windows could (easily) be the subject of a fairly substantial book.

Comment: @Dokkat So your question is how to implement a debugger? That's even broader (I wouldn't even be so sure that one substantial book would be enough to cover everything for that) and would involve quite a lot of work which wouldn't help your final goal.

Comment: Any question can be as broad as you want, this doesn't mean you can't answer it. For example, even if someone asked 'how are computer programs made', you could simply say they are usually made by writting source code, obeying to the rules of a programming language, and using tools that will compile that code to a working binary. That's probably everything the asker wants o know. He can then proceed to google such languages and tools himself. What I want here is just to know where to get started, as I have no idea, at all. You know? Not knowing what to google for. That's horrible.

Comment: @Voo no, I just, simply want to know how to access the memory block of another program - IF that's how those tools are made, which was a guess - and, if not, I want the answer to point how they are actually made.

Comment: @Dokkat: Okay, for Windows, you might start with `VirtualQueryEx`, `ReadProcessMemory` and `WriteProcessMemory`. They probably won't be *sufficient*, but will probably all be necessary, and documentation on them will probably have links to many other things you'll need.

Comment: @JerryCoffin perfect, I'll be googling those now. If that does the job that probably answers the question. Thanks!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As you might know, all instructions/data of an application are saved at specific offsets in memory, usually set by the compiler. Using debuggers/disassemblers (eg. ollydbg) or memory "searchers" (eg. CheatEngine), you can view these.
One easy process would be searching memory for a given value (ingame health for example) and then change it through game dynamics and repeat the search till you have the memory address of the value in question, which usually is static i.e: doesn't change till the executable gets updated. (In reality techniques like ASLR are used to randomize but can be circumvented)

Now using that acquired address, you can produce a handler which deals with it either through using the Windows API to perform mouseclicks/keystrokes or through calling the ingame functions, which addresses and arguments can also be found by debugging. (Example: if health < 50%, call this function)

Another way is to use a proxy through which all traffic is routed, and where you can inject outgoing packets to perform actions, or parse incoming ones to deduce conditions.

Obviously, I can't provide sample code but you could start by reading about reverse engineering basics and packetsniffing, and practice by solving crackmes and following tutorials for cheating on single player games like the ones on the CheatEngine forums.

You could also check this chatlog about botting and countermeasures as explained to a non-programmer:
http://pastebin.com/6WWif7gK
(Start at :20)

Comment: Your answer was one of the best I ever got in SO, thank you very much. Where did you get that chatlog?

Comment: The level 32 in the conversation is me ^^

Comment: oh awesome. Can I contact you by email or other mean?